# How to convert a spark dataframe to a list of structs in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe composed of 12 rows and different columns, 22 in this case.

I want to convert it into a dataframe of the format:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- ast: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- blk: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dreb: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fg3_pct: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fg3a: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fg3m: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fg_pct: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fga: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fgm: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ft_pct: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fta: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ftm: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- games_played: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- seconds: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- oreb: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pf: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- player_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pts: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- reb: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- season: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- stl: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- turnover: double (nullable = true)
```

Where each element of the dataframe `data` field corresponds to a different row of the original dataframe.

The final goal is exporting it to *.json* file which will have the format:

```
{"data": [{row1}, {row2}, ..., {row12}]}
```

The code I am employing at the moment is the following:

```
val best_12_struct = best_12.withColumn("data", array((0 to 11).map(i => struct(col("ast"), col("blk"), col("dreb"), col("fg3_pct"), col("fg3a"), 
                                                                   col("fg3m"), col("fg_pct"), col("fga"), col("fgm"), 
                                                                   col("ft_pct"), col("fta"), col("ftm"), col("games_played"), 
                                                                   col("seconds"), col("oreb"), col("pf"), col("player_id"), 
                                                                   col("pts"), col("reb"), col("season"), col("stl"), col("turnover"))) : _*))
            
val best_12_data = best_12_struct.select("data")
```

But the `array(0 to 11)` copies 12 times the same element into `data`. Therefore, the `.json` I finally obtain has 12 `{"data": ...}`, being in each the same row copied 12 times, instead of just one `{"data": ...}` with 12 elements, corresponding each to one row of the original dataframe.

Comment: can you add sample data and expected output in json ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 12 times the same row as the method `withColumn` will only pick information from the current treated row.

You need to aggregate rows at dataframe level with `collect_list` that is an [aggregate function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#aggregate-functions) as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val best_12_data = best_12
  .withColumn("row", struct(col("ast"), col("blk"), col("dreb"), col("fg3_pct"), col("fg3a"), col("fg3m"), col("fg_pct"), col("fga"), col("fgm"), col("ft_pct"), col("fta"), col("ftm"), col("games_played"), col("seconds"), col("oreb"), col("pf"), col("player_id"), col("pts"), col("reb"), col("season"), col("stl"), col("turnover")))
  .agg(collect_list(col("row")).as("data"))
```